# How can I specify type for an "opaque" struct declaration with Cython? (empty struct `pa_threaded_mainloop` in PulseAudio)

Tags: python, audio, cython, pulseaudio

So first, the high-level problem (though the question is, *I think* a general cython question):

I'm using a raspberry pi to control some LEDs over an I2C bus. I'd like to control these by snooping the audio and doing fun signal-processing things, and it seems the most robust way to do this would be with PulseAudio (for example, registering callbacks is something I can't do with ALSA AFAICT). Available python bindings to PulseAudio aren't for the right version, and since I'm planning to use some relatively heavy signal processing libraries (which would work with numpy arrays), I may as well use cython.

I'm not sure it's relevant, but Raspbian wheezy ships with PulseAudio 2.0. If you're using a synchronous system to interact with PulseAudio, the docs recommend using the threaded mainloop. In particular, `/usr/include/pulse/pulse/thread-mainloop.h` includes these declarations:

```c
/** An opaque threaded main loop object */
typedef struct pa_threaded_mainloop pa_threaded_mainloop;

/** Allocate a new threaded main loop object. You have to call
 * pa_threaded_mainloop_start() before the event loop thread starts
 * running. */
pa_threaded_mainloop *pa_threaded_mainloop_new(void);
```

This seems like a reasonable place to get started. In particular, my understanding is that cython doesn't need full type information specified in the .pyx file - I have no plan of digging into the guts of that struct, and simply letting the pulseaudio functions operate on it. So, here's my `pulse.pyx` file:

```
cimport cython                                                                  

cdef extern from "pulse/thread-mainloop.h":                                     
    cdef struct pa_threaded_mainloop:                                           
        pass                                                                    
    pa_threaded_mainloop pa_threaded_mainloop_new()
```

Just that much will actually compile. (I *think* I should be using a `cdef` here, but I get the same errors with a `ctypedef`.) If I add a line that just calls that function at the end of `pulse.pyx`:

```
pa_threaded_mainloop_new()
```

That works. But if I try to do anything with the return value, like:

```
mainloop = pa_threaded_mainloop_new()
```

or specifying a `cdef`ed variable (or doing the cdef on a different line):

```
cdef mainloop = pa_threaded_mainloop_new()
```

I get an error at compile time:

```
pulse.c: In function ‘initpulse’:
pulse.c:659:3: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
pulse.c: At top level:
pulse.c:873:88: error: parameter 1 (‘s’) has incomplete type
```

I get a slightly different error with `cdef pa_threaded_mainloop mainloop`:

```
pulse.c: In function ‘initpulse’:
pulse.c:656:3: error: ‘__pyx_v_5pulse_mainloop’ has an incomplete type
```

So, how might I go about correctly letting cython know about the PulseAudio 2.0 library? Note that I have directly installed cython 0.21, and more prosaic stuff like calling out to the standard C library works fine.

Comment: In C opaque types are used for one reason: Hiding **all the details**. You should never handle the opaque type itself, only ever pointers.

Comment: OK, now I am very embarassed. I am so disused to reading C code that I missed the `*` in the function definition. Thanks for the comment, it immediately got me to the fix.